# Redirect inside a getInitialProps with next.js and Parse Server

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, next.js, parse-server, parse-javascript-sdk

EDIT :

I set a cookie when the user is connected et store the token inside a cookie. And with the `GetInitialProps`i access to the cookie and i check if the session is set to an user or not.

It seems it only work when i access to this page when i use a link : home page to this page for exemple but when i type the url it doesn't work.

I'm using `npm install --save next-cookies` for retrieve the cookie :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-cookies

I'm sorry it's probably a stupid question but i'm still learning ...

Here is the whole code of my page Login.js

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react'
import Parse from 'parse'
import Snackbar from '@material-ui/core/Snackbar';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'
import cookies from 'next-cookies'

export default function login() {

    const [state, setState] = React.useState({
        username: "",
        password: "",
    }
    )

    const [error, setError] = useState(false)

    async function handleConnection() {
        try {
            const user = await Parse.User.logIn(state.username, state.password)
            console.log(user)

            var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
            const token = currentUser.getSessionToken()
            //console.log(token)
            Cookies.set('token', token, { expires: 365 })
            setError(false)
        } catch (e) {
            setError(true)
        }
    }
    function handleChange(evt) {
        const value = evt.target.value;
        setState({
            ...state,
            [evt.target.name]: value
        });
    }

    return (
        <div className="notConnected container-fluid">
            <div className="containerFormLogin">
                <h1>Connectez-vous !</h1>
                <p>{error ? "Nom d'utilisateur ou mot de passe incorrect" : ''}</p>
                <label>Nom d'utilisateur ou mail</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" onChange={handleChange} />
                <label>Mot de passe</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" onChange={handleChange} />
                <button className="pulse" onClick={handleConnection}>Se connecter</button>
                <p>Pas encore de compte ? Inscrivez-vous par ici !</p>
                <Snackbar
                    anchorOrigin={{ vertical: "bottom", horizontal: "center" }}
                    open={error}
                    autoHideDuration={3000}
                    message={<span id="message-id">Impossible de se connecter, vérifier vos informations de connexion</span>}
                    ContentProps={{
                        "aria-describedby": "message-id"
                    }}
                ></Snackbar>
            </div>
            <style jsx>{`

                .notConnected
                {
                    background-image: url('/images/notConnected.svg');
                    height: 100vh;
                    width: 100%;
                    background-position: center;
                    background-size: cover;
                    background-repeat: no-repeat;
                    display: flex,
                }
                p:empty
                {
                    margin:0 !important;
                }
                .containerFormLogin
                {
                    width: 400px;
                    background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.8);
                    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5) 10px 10px 10px;
                    border-radius: 10px;
                    display: flex;
                    flex-direction: column;
                    padding: 30px;
                    margin:auto;
                    transition: all .2s ease-in;
                }
                .containerFormLogin:hover
                {
                    background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 1);
                }
                .containerFormLogin h1
                {
                    margin-bottom: 40px;
                    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
                    font-size: 25px;
                    text-align: center;
                }
                .containerFormLogin p
                {
                    font-size: 12px;
                    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
                    margin-top: 10px;
                }
                .containerFormLogin label
                {
                    font-size: 12px;
                    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
                }
                .containerFormLogin input
                {
                    margin-bottom: 20px;
                    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
                    font-size: 15px;
                    padding-top: 10px;
                    padding-bottom: 10px;

                }
                .error
                {
                    border-color: red;
                }
                button 
                {
                background: none;
                border: 2px solid;
                font: inherit;
                line-height: 1;
                padding: 1em 2em;
                color:  #ef6eae;
                -webkit-transition: 0.25s;
                transition: 0.25s;
                }
                button:hover, button:focus {
                border-color: #ef8f6e;
                color: #ef8f6e;
                }
                .pulse:hover,
                .pulse:focus {
                -webkit-animation: pulse 1s;
                        animation: pulse 1s;
                box-shadow: 0 0 0 2em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
                }

                @-webkit-keyframes pulse {
                0% {
                    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #ef8f6e;
                }
                }

                @keyframes pulse {
                0% {
                    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #ef8f6e;
                }
                }

            `}</style>
        </div >
    )
}

login.getInitialProps = (ctx) => {

    const allCookies = cookies(ctx).token;

    const UserToken = Parse.User.me(allCookies)
    if (UserToken) {
        // the user is connected so we do the redirection beacause when he's connected he can't have access to this page
        return (
            UserToken
        )
    } else {
        // Do something else

    }


}
```

EDIT #2 :

When i reach the page with a link like homePage to the login page i have this error

`Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): res is undefined`

and when I'm reloading the page or if i access by his url he give me an other error :

`ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined`

Here is my getInitialProps:

```
connexion.getInitialProps = ({ ctx, res }) => {

    const cookies = Cookies.get('tokenUserParse');

    const UserToken = Parse.User.me(cookies)
    if (UserToken) {
        // the user is connected so we do the redirection beacause when he's connected he can't have access to this page

        res.writeHead(403, {
            Location: '/'
        });
        res.end();

    } else {
        // Do something else

    }
}
```

Comment: You can't use `Parse.User.current()` function in the server side.

Comment: Ok thank you, so i need to put condition for render this component or an other when i use ```Parse.User.current() ```

Comment: Now I believe that you have a different question :) When your user logs in your frontend side you need to store its session token in a cookie. In your `getInitialProps` function you will have to check if it is running in the client or the server. When in client, you can just use Parse.User.current(), but when in the server, you have to retrieve the session token from the cookie and use Parse.User.me(sessionToken) to return the logged user. Give it a try and edit the question/open a new one with your code.

Comment: Ty for the help, i edit my question with my code , i'm not sure that i'm on the right way ...

Comment: It looks you are in the right direction. What is not working now?

Comment: I edit my Post with the problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that the same code that you have in `getInitialProps` will run both in the server (Node.js environment) and in the browser (javascript). Some libraries will work well for both environments but some libraries won't. So sometimes you need to perform different actions depending on which environment the code is running in. Something like this should fix your problem:

```js
const isServer = typeof window === 'undefined';

const Parse = isServer ? require('parse/node') : require('parse');

connexion.getInitialProps = async ({ ctx, res }) => {

    const cookies = Cookies.get('tokenUserParse');

    const UserToken = await Parse.User.me(cookies)
    if (UserToken) {
        // the user is connected so we do the redirection beacause when he's connected he can't have access to this page

        if (isServer) {
            res.writeHead(302, {
                Location: '/'
            });
            res.end();
        } else {
            document.location.href = '/'
        }
    } else {
        // Do something else

    }
}
```